# Change in game volume for Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

So I'm routing my STB through my Xbone, and to have a decent volume range (the STB has it's own), I turn my TV volume up to 50%. The really annoying this is that when my TV is on anything above 20%, everyone in the neighborhood goes deaf.

It's very annoying to have to keep changing this, and if I keep my TV at 20% I can't hear the STB on it's full volume. Is there a way to control either in game volume, or set my Xbone to have all apps/games at a certain volume?

Everything I can find is for either headsets or custom music etc, nothing useful.

Comment: What is an STB?

Comment: provided you find no other solution, as a terrible hack you can set the volume of the app when the snap is open and then just leave your snap window up...

Comment: sorry @Rapitor, Set Top Box, for TV.

Comment: @Eben, how would I do that?

Comment: it's in the audio settings for you system where you set how much volume fade there is during a snapped app... I left these not as answers because I haven't looked up the specific instructions

Comment: @Eben thanks, may as well just change the volume though